# differentiability of functions f and g

Tags: real-analysis

Exactly one of the requests is impossible. Provide examples for the other three. Assume functions $f$ and $g$ are defined on all of **R**.

(i) Functions $f$ and $g$ not differentiable at zero but where $fg$ is differentiable at $0$.

(ii) A function $f$ is not differentiable at zero and a function $g$ differentiable at zero where $fg$ is differentiable at $0$.

*My answer: let $f=sin(1/x)$ and $g=0$*

(iii) A function $f$ not differentiable at zero and a function $g$ differentiable at zero where $f+g$ is differentiable at zero.

(iv) A function $f$ differentiable at zero but not differentiable anywhere else.

I'm not looking for the answers, just looking for some guidance. I have been trying to think of examples for a while but still cannot get anything. Closest I have came is trying to create a piecewise continous function using Weierstrass for Part (iv) so that it can be differentiable at $0$. Still haven't figured it out though.

Answer (score 3):

Let's get wild here.

For (i): Define $f$ to be $0$ on $(-\infty,0],$ define $g$ to be $0$ on $[0,\infty)$ and define these functions to be a complete disaster everywhere else.

(ii) What is the easiest, flattest, most stupid differentiable function $g$ on $\mathbb {R}$ that you know?

(iii) $f = (f+g) - g.$

(iv) Note that if $|f(x)|\le x^2$ for all $x,$ then $f'(0)=0.$ That leaves a lot of room for $f$ to misbehave elsewhere.

Comment: I liked the beer. Why did you remove it?

Comment: I thought the MSE elders might not like it. By the way Boris, I like your novels.

Comment: thank you for the help. I have (i) and (ii) done. Like I said in response to the other answer.. I'm having trouble determining which function request is impossible.

Comment: also, I'm not sure if I understand your hint for part (iii). it seems like that would be the impossible request. It is requesting two functions (one diff at 0, the other not) such that the sum is differentiable at 0. I would imagine I have to actually define two functions.

Comment: If $u,v$ are differentiable at $0,$ isn't $u-v$ differentiable at $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Heres one for the first example:

i) $f$ is the step function where $f(x)$ is $1$ if $x\ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise. $g$ is the step function where $g(x)=1$ if $x<0$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $fg(x)=0$ for all $x$.

In general it is useful to think about step functions since they have easy discontinuities. Also take advantage of $0$ like we did above. Another tip is you may consider steps which "cancel out" when you add them together, creating a straight line.

Comment: Yes. that example works for (i). I had that function in mind - it's useful for a lot of examples similar to these.

Comment: I supposed the hardest part to my question is determining which of the four requests is impossible

Comment: I would definitely go with number 3. I don't think it would be terrible to prove, either, but you would need some definitions. Also I'm glad you pointed out that one of them is impossible; I was getting confused looking at the third one.

Comment: @Elliot Since it doesn't say $f \neq g$, why not just let $f(x)=g(x) = |x|$? Then $fg = x^2$, which is everywhere differentiable.